# Recyclerview inside coordinator layout not scrolls

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have following activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:id="@+id/catalog_view">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:background="@color/gray238"
        android:id="@+id/top_separator"/>

    ..

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/check_view_sheet"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

check_view_sheet

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/check_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
       app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">


    <FrameLayout
         app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="235dp"
        android:id="@+id/catalog_view_check_fragment"
        />

    <TotalView.TotalView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/totalViewHeight"
        android:id="@+id/catalog_total_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

View inside framelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/check_recycler_view"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/checkBottomPadding"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that recycler view is not scrolling.

I tried wrapping `framelayout` in `nestedScrollView`, but performance of scroll is horrible - its very laggy and it hides sheet when I try to scroll recycler view down.

How canto fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying do nested scrolling, bottom sheet has scrollable behavior.

try this in RecyclerView

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

if scrolling it in bottom sheet is really mandatory otherwise try by setting it to "false".

Comment: Try to add the views inside Nested Scoll View

Comment: I wrote about nested scrollview in question